# Sampling distributions question

Tags: statistics

LEt x bar be the mean of a random sample of size n=48 from the uniform distribution on the interval (0,2); that is, f(x) =1/2 for 0

for this problem i am confused because don't we need to know mean and standard deviation for this.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what the question is. Also, you can calculate the mean and standard deviation for a uniform random variable.

Comment: so how would i go about calculating them

Comment: First Google hit for how to calculate mean and variance of uniform distribution, second page. http://www.personal.soton.ac.uk/jav/soton/HELM/workbooks/workbook_38/38_2_uniform_dist.pdf

Answer (score 0):

yeah so here is how i got around solving it 
mean= integral from 0 to 2 of 0.5x = 1, stand dev=integral from o to 2 of 0.5x^2 -1=1/3
so for our problem mean is 1 and st dev = .577/sq root 48=.083 so
P(0.9 < x<1.1)=.8849-.1151=.7698